# Unable to find the socket transport "tls" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm using wamp to run, but i got this warning at run time:

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to tls://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "tls" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in C:\wamp\www\mail\testemail.php on line 24
>   Unable to find the socket transport "tls" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: The same problem and solution, except the missing transport was 'ssl' in my case.

Answer (score 15):

You need to enable SSL/TLS for your Apache/PHP installation. 
Make sure you have libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in your /apache/bin folder.
Edit your php.ini file and add

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Then restart Apache and your SSL should be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WAMP on Windows you can left click on the green W in the notifications pane.

Then goto:
PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_openssl

Once you do that WAMP should auto restart and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenSuSE Linux 11.3

Required tls (Tcl Binding for the OpenSSL Library) and php5-openssl packages. Easily added with the yast software manager after a repository refresh.